# How to make the Form elements work correctly when referencing in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom, compiler-construction

I am doing a simple practical test on how to work with form elements in JavaScript, which I don't quite understand what is wrong. I checked the web browser's firebug and the console gives no error, which I thought was odd. How am I suppose to know what went wrong, if it didn't give errors. This is the most frustrating part as I need a compiler to easily detect and fix the errors. I use Notepad++ with the JS script embedded in the HTML file. Anything that would help me efficiently understand and do JavaScript the right way would be great by referring to a software that does better or website, whatever that will enhance my understanding of it because I still don't get it and keep getting a lot of things wrong and even worst, the web console shows nothing or when I make an obvious error.

When a user clicks on the button it will create a textbox underneath it, provided checked, if not, it will remove it and replace with textnode. Here's the code: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KTZ89/)

**JavaScript:**

```
function frm1
    {
        var form1 = document.getElementById("form1");

        btnCreate.onClick = function()
        {
            if(cbCheck.checked)
            {
                var txt = form1.createElement("input");
                txt.type = "text";
                txt.setAttribute("text","Write Here!");
            }
            else if(!cbCheck.checked)
            {
                form1.removeChild(txt);
                var para = form1.createElement("p");
                para.createTextNode("Text Removed!");
                para.setAttribute("style","color:red;");
                form1.appendChild(para);
            }
        }
    }
```

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Practical 340 Review JS</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script type="text/javascript" href="test.js">

    function frm1
    {
        var form1 = document.getElementById("form1");

        btnCreate.onClick = function()
        {
            if(cbCheck.checked)
            {
                var txt = form1.createElement("input");
                txt.type = "text";
                txt.setAttribute("text","Write Here!");
            }
            else if(!cbCheck.checked)
            {
                form1.removeChild(txt);
                var para = form1.createElement("p");
                para.createTextNode("Text Removed!");
                para.setAttribute("style","color:red;");
                form1.appendChild(para);
            }
        }
    }

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="prob1">
    <h1>Form Elements</h1>
    <form id="form1">
        <p>Checked?<input type="checkbox" name="cbCheck" value="Checked?"/></p>
        <input type="button" value="Create" name="btnCreate"/>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="prob2">

</div>

<div id="prob3">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the best tools you can use for debugging JavaScript is the built-in JS debuggers available in all modern browsers. I don't remember what the tab is named in Firefox, but in Chrome, there's a "sources" tab where you can set breakpoints in your code. When the browser executes that code, it will stop on that line and wait for you to tell it to continue. While the code is paused, you can inspect the values of variables etc.

Your code had a couple of problems, which I'll try to list. I've also created a new fiddle with working code.

http://jsfiddle.net/itsananderson/KTZ89/8/

- Function declarations require parens. Your "frm1" didn't have them
- You never called "frm1", so the code never ran
- JavaScript doesn't automatically create variables for form elements, so you have to create them yourself. See `btnCreate` and `cbCheck`.
- You can't do `form1.createElement`. Instead do `document.createElement`. Same with `createTextNode`

Here's the updated JavaScript:

```
  function frm1() {
    var form1 = document.getElementById("form1");

    var txt = document.createElement("input");
    txt.type = "text";
    txt.setAttribute("value","Write Here!");

    var para = document.createElement("p");
    para.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Text Removed!"));
    para.setAttribute("style","color:red;");

    form1['btnCreate'].onclick = function()
    {
        var cbCheck = form1['cbCheck'];
        if(cbCheck.checked)
        {
            form1.appendChild(txt);
            if (para.parentNode){
                para.parentNode.removeChild(para);
            }
        }
        else if(!cbCheck.checked)
        {
            if (txt.parentNode) {   
                txt.parentNode.removeChild(txt);
                form1.appendChild(para);
            }
        }
    }
}
frm1();
```

Comment: Interesting, your code works in JSfiddle, but not in the web browser. Up to line `form1['btnCreate'].onclick = function()`, the debugging will stop and not continue. Maybe the syntax for this code is wrong?

Comment: Do you have an "in the web browser" example that I can look at? There's probably some extra piece of code, or some DOM change that's causing it to not work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "in the web browser" example? I just copied your code into the embedded script and wouldn't execute in the browser due to that line.

Comment: I looked at your inline example again, and I see the problem. Your JavaScript is above the `<form>` on the page, so when it runs, the browser hasn't yet loaded the form into the DOM. Move your `<script>` tag below the form and it should work. Also, you don't need the `href="test.js"` part because your source is inline.

Comment: I never knew you could take the javascript code and put it after the form. I know javascript by putting it in the `<head>` tag or in a external file and call them using `document.getElementById(id);`. But I also like your approach as well. Can you tell me the reason why you put it inline (the HTML after the form) like so? Is it because the browser will then recognize the `name` value used such as `form1['btnCreate']` instead of it being embedded or put in a separate file where it isn't detected by the browser? Thanks!

Comment: A `<script>` tag that references an external script *might* work because of the delay of the browser fetching the script, but there's no guarantee. If you want your script in the header, put your code in a function attached to the `window.onload` event. The problem with your script in the header was actually that `document.getElementById('form1')` will return `undefined`. It just doesn't break until `form1['btnCreate']` when you actually try to use `form1`

Comment: Actually, `document.getElementById` returns `null` not `undefined` if the id isn't found. Sorry for the misinformation